# How to set viso2_ros stereo parameters?

Tags: ros, stereo, viso2-ros, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I'm trying to using stereo odometry with viso2_ros library. How to set the distance from left camera to right camera?
Which camera is related to base_link -> camera tf transformation? The right camera or the left camera?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46614/how-to-set-viso2_ros-stereo-parameters?/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The base camera frame for a stereo system is the left optical frame.
The viso2_ros stereo odometer reads all information including baseline from the corresponding camera info messages (i.e. `<stereo>/left/camera_info` and `<stereo>right/camera_info`). Be sure to [calibrate your stereo system using the camera_calibration package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration)!

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lily](https://answers.ros.org/users/8556/lily/) on 2014-03-20**:
Do you mean that if I want to use viso2_ros I should first use the camera calibration package you mentioned to get the calibration parameters? Can't I use other calibration method? How about the parameters in libviso2?  Is that the same situation? Because my results of libviso2 always have scale problem and sometimes monocular trajectory seems better than stereo.  I think maybe it is the parameters problem.